# Is it essential to install ubuntu on mac OC system to perform WGS and RNA-Seq analysis efficiently

Tags: linux, macos, coding-style, bioinformatics, data-analysis

I am following a workflow guide to perform WGS and Rna-Seq analysis ...unfortunately, this guide is built based on Linux system. However, I am trying to perform similar packages commands using mac terminal. I installed anaconda and created environment based on python (with all bioinformatics packages)!! but I am still facing coding errors..
How can we modify codes to fit Mac OS!!

Comment: The package might not be compatible with MacOS. Have you consider installing Ubuntu/Linux using bootcamp and do a dual boot?

Comment: Hi Tom Tom, I am not familiar with bootcamp...could you please suggest the best way to install ubuntu ....do you recommend  virtual box!!

Comment: You should use a virtual box with Ubuntu installed on it

Comment: I recommend you to install UBUNTU on your computer and forget the Mac OS.. use an old computer if you don't want to install it on your Mac.. the virtual box enables you to experiment UBUNTU, but to run and analyse large datasets it is very difficult.. you'll probably lose a lot of time and experience many bugs..

Answer (score 0):

Based on the commments, you can install the Ubuntu on VirtualBox so that you can have a proper linux experience.

To download it straight, here is the link to it - https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Here I also found a guide for it  - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aJcc-xC6krE

Good luck!